# USB adapter freezes everything when connected

Tags: usb, 22.04

The adapter in question is the Mokin mouc0501. I see the following strange behaviour once I plug it in with the power being available, no USB devide the HDMI port is working, it is as if they were not there. If I unplug the cables and put them in the USB and HDMI ports, everything is fine.

The odd thing here is that the hub works flawlesly on a Macbook and on a Windows machine, those two having different OSes makes the whole experience odd.

```shell
arch

x86_64
```

and

```shell
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```